# Voximal - Cannot test the application

Tags: voximal

I've just installed the app on my asterisk 14 and i got some problems.
I've created this account in voximal.conf

```
[account2]
number=8000
name=test1
url=file:///var/lib/voximal/test.vxml
```

This is the content of my test.vxml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<vxml version = "2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml">
 <form>
  <block><audio src="hello.wav"/></block>
 </form>
</vxml>
```

This is the content of my extensions.conf file

```
exten => 8000,1,Answer
exten => 8000,n,Wait(2)
exten => 8000,n,Voximal(test1)
exten => 8000,n,Hangup
```

And this is what I get when I call 8000 on my softphone

```
Executing [8000@from-internal:1] Answer("PJSIP/marc-00000005", "") in new stack
       > 0x7fcbfc150140 -- Strict RTP learning after remote address set to: 192.168.79.1:40034
       > 0x7fcbfc150140 -- Strict RTP switching to RTP target address 192.168.79.1:40034 as source
    -- Executing [8000@from-internal:2] Wait("PJSIP/marc-00000005", "2") in new stack
       > 0x7fcbfc150140 -- Strict RTP learning complete - Locking on source address 192.168.79.1:40034
    -- Executing [8000@from-internal:3] Voximal("PJSIP/marc-00000005", "test1") in new stack
[Jan  3 09:15:56] ERROR[48508][C-00000006]: app_voximal.c:20285 vxml_exec: Cannot open new session, allocating context!
    -- Executing [8000@from-internal:4] Hangup("PJSIP/marc-00000005", "") in new stack
```

I've tried this to identify the error:

```
exten => 8000,1,Voximal()
exten => 8000,n,NoOp(${VOXIMAL_ERROR})
exten => 8000,n,GotoIf($["${VOXIMAL_ERROR}" == ""]?hangup)
exten => 8000,n,Busy()
exten => 8000,n(hangup),Hangup()
```

And I got this:

```
Executing [8000@from-internal:1] Voximal("PJSIP/marc-00000000", "") in new stack
[Jan  3 09:28:08] ERROR[48842][C-00000001]: app_voximal.c:20285 vxml_exec: Cannot open new session, allocating context!
    -- Executing [8000@from-internal:2] NoOp("PJSIP/marc-00000000", "LICENSE") in new stack
    -- Executing [8000@from-internal:3] GotoIf("PJSIP/marc-00000000", "0?hangup") in new stack
    -- Executing [8000@from-internal:4] Busy("PJSIP/marc-00000000", "") in new stack
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

The error : vxml_exec: Cannot open new session, allocating context!

It is because you didn't have enable the free 1 port of Voximal.
Have a look to your Voxiaml Licence with :
CLI> voximal show license

The default configuration needs an Internet connection to get the license.
If you are testing in a secure network, you need to set the key=evaluation (in the voximal.conf file or from the Web Interface) to enable localy the test/dev/free license.

Comment: Ok thank you! I've already set the key=trial and it works! I can execute some local vxml files. But when I try to reach a distant location, nothing again. And this time VOXIMAL_ERROR is empty! I don't know, maybe the trial license doesn't give access to distant location, there is no information about licenses on the Voximal website!

Comment: I think you proably have network issues.
The Voximal trial/free version have the full features abled (the only limitation is the 1 port).
The catch the error, have a look to the log file in /var/log/voximal/debug.
If you not see the cause, try again with more logs with :
CLI> voximal debug interpreter

Comment: OK!! I use a proxy to get Internet access, maybe that is the cause of my network issues. How can I handle this? Use Voximal with a proxy

Comment: From standard configuration/integration, you need to enable the voximald.conf file in /etc : so copy the file voximald.conf and voximald_defaults.xml from the package tarball to the /etc.
With the configuration file voximald.conf, you will be able to enable the proxy using. Those parameters are for experiemented and technical guys (and girls). The comments in the file will help you. To update changes done, you need to restart the Voximal interpreter (by restarting the Asterisk).